# Error when trying to upload local files to Drive with Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am trying to upload local files to my Drive using the Drive API from Google but I am having some issues when implementing my code in VS Code.
I am using the Google's Official API from
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

```
clientpath=r'\path'
nameclientfile='client_secret.json'
clientoken='token.json'
CLIENT_SECRET = os.path.join(clientpath, nameclientfile)
TOKEN_JSON=os.path.join(clientpath, clientoken)



from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists(TOKEN_JSON):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(TOKEN_JSON, SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(TOKEN_JSON, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])
main()
```

the full trace of the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-a524b029f47e> in <module>
     51         for label in labels:
     52             print(label['name'])
---> 53 main()

<ipython-input-31-a524b029f47e> in main()
     26     # time.
     27     if os.path.exists(TOKEN_JSON):
---> 28         creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(TOKEN_JSON, SCOPES)
     29     # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
     30     if not creds or not creds.valid:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\credentials.py in from_authorized_user_file(cls, filename, scopes)
    324         with io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
    325             data = json.load(json_file)
--> 326             return cls.from_authorized_user_info(data, scopes)
    327 
    328     def to_json(self, strip=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\credentials.py in from_authorized_user_info(cls, info, scopes)
    275 
    276         if missing:
--> 277             raise ValueError(
    278                 "Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing "
    279                 "fields {}.".format(", ".join(missing))

ValueError: Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing fields client_secret, refresh_token, client_id.
```

how the token.json file shoul look like?

Comment: are you sure that code resulted in that error message?

Comment: every time I run the script..

Comment: why are you not using Google's own python library? Have a look at [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

Comment: I edited it with the official google's API

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: There is something wrong with client_secret.json either you have the wrong type or your code cant find the file at all.

Comment: Do you use a client secret or a service account key file? Can you share the client_secret.json content, with all the sensitive data redacted?